# How to set up multiple monitor displays for best picture quality?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have two 1080p monitors that I'm trying to build a dual monitor setup with, they both have 1 HDMI port and 1 VGA port each. I wanted to connect both monitors to each other using a HDMI cable and then use another HDMI cable to connect to the computer because I heard HDMI offers better picture quality than VGA.

But since I only have 1 HDMI port in each monitor, I have to connect the 2 monitors using VGA and use HDMI to connect one of the monitors to the computer. Would this reduce picture quality at all? Will connecting both monitors via HDMI and using VGA to connect to the computer be any better?

Would using a HDMI splitter cable be better?

**tl;dr: wanted to use HDMI cables for everything but am forced to also use VGA in combination, will this reduce picture quality?**

Comment: I am assuming you want both monitors to show the same thing?  Or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **You cannot daisy-chain multiple HDMI monitors the way you are thinking!**

Both screens must be directly connected to your computer, not each other.  Also an HDMI splitter is out of the question too.  A splitter would only make the same image come out on both screens, which would be pointless.

---

You never actually said in your question how many connections your computer has.  I assume it has one HDMI and one VGA. If that's the case, your only option is to connect one screen with HDMI and connect the other with  VGA.

As far as image quality is concerned, for the average person on an average-sized screen, you would be hard-pressed to tell the difference between HDMI and VGA if you use a short, high-quality VGA cable.  At worst, images may appear slightly less sharp and crisp, or there might be a tiny amount of ghosting.  There could also be a slight "snowy" pattern in the screen.  At best, you will see no difference at all.

Any image quality difference that could be seen between a digital connection and a good analog one would be highly subjective.  Obviously HDMI is the better option, but it doesn't sound like you have a choice.  One of your screens is going to need VGA.

Comment: I didn't realize the process for setting up multiple monitors. I was able to get it to work finally by connecting one to the laptop using VGA and the other to the laptop using HDMI. Since the laptop only has 1 HDMI port I had to make use of the VGA. Only question I have now is, if I used a HDMI splitter and connected both monitors to the laptop using 2 HDMI cables, will that work? Never used a splitter before so don't know...

Comment: A splitter only duplicates the same HDMI source to multiple displays. You would use a one in situations where you needed the same thing to show on more than one screen. Like if you were running a presentation for example, where you needed the same image on your screen and the overhead projector. Or if you're an electronics store and you want the same movie from one DVD player to show on dozens of TV models that you sell. That sort of thing. A splitter will not give you two screens. It will give you one screen in two places.

Answer (score 0):

Compare VGA and HDMI with Radio and Digital TV, max. output of VGA is 640x480.

Connecting screen to screen is known as 'Daisychaining'

DVI and HDMI display 1080 / +HDMI ports audio

To chain them one to another you'd need 'Displayport' or 'miniDisplayport' (now also the new standard of HDMI) BUT foremost one display needs to deliver a OUTPUT in form of HDMI(1.4) / mDP / DP

Which 'computer' are you working with / windows10 linux macOS? TowerPC or Notebook?

Even with a Laptop it's possible, maybe a little bit pricier. However, it always depends on your needs:

OFFICE
- Get a 'USB3 to HDMI' converter, this solution is perfect for office apps, email, surf, just not higher than ~30 fps (frames per second)
~30/50$

CAD VIDEO GAMING
- Get a GPU (graphic processing unit) good enough for your needs, put it in your motherbord, and connect both screens to it (gpu)
-- You can get older, cheaper GPUs with 2 DVIs, then using  DVI>HDMI cables, it's always 1080
~50/300$base
~400/900$nice
+1000$ enthusiast
or ask a friend if he got an older one laying around

- As said, it works with laptops, on windows and macos (linux should work too), but you have to do it yourself. Google 'DIY GPU howto' - You'll build an external case with your gpu og choice

Alternatively you can get a external Dock that splitts the signal to 2 outputs. Normally they cost a lot, but got a lot of features. Buy this if you can connect your notebook with TB(Thunderbolt) to it, else get the USB3>HDMI converter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VGA is analog where HDMI is digital.  Thus HDMI will give you better picture quality.

If you only have one HDMI output on your computer, you will have to use something else like VGA for the other.  You connect both monitors directly to the computer, not to each other.

If you want both displays to show the same thing, you are correct that an HDMI splitter would be better.

If you want a dual monitor setup to extend your desktop, you can either go the VGA route or get a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter.  Those are now showing up on the market for pretty cheap.